# $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} (y\cos^2(x/y))/(y+x^4) \, dx$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

How do I calculate the limit

$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{y\cos^2(x/y)}{y+x^4} \, dx?
$$

It's about measure theory.

I though about Fatou's lemma, but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: i think the limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

The change of variable $x=y^{1/4}z$ shows that the integral is $$I(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{y\cos^2(x/y)}{y+x^4} \, dx=y^{1/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos^2(z/y^{3/4})}{1+z^4} \, dz.
$$
The integral on the RHS converges to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac1{1+z^4} \, dz=c\gt0,
$$ hence $I(y)\sim cy^{1/4}$, and the limit follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{y\cos^2(x/y)}{y+x^4}$; this is a positive function.
We have $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(x,y)=1$ for every $x>0$.
By Fatou's lemma
$$
\int_0^\infty\liminf_{y\to\infty}f(x,y) dx
\leq
\liminf_{y\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f(x,y) dx.
$$
The LHS is $\int_0^\infty1dx=\infty$, so the desired limit is infinite.